# How to translate "The Tale of Squirrel Nutkin" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

I was told to translate "The Tale of Squirrel Nutkin" before wednesday into German. I put it on Google: "Die Geschichte von Eichhörnchen-Nusskin". Is it correct German and does it rightly translate the book's title?

I tried to find a [German wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Squirrel_Nutkin) that could help me translate it but it doesn't seem to exist.

I have to confess you I know no words of German and I'm looking for primary help to confirm the translation, a 8 german speaking year old kid could have help me but I know none.

Comment: There is a translation of the book that is titled “Die Geschichte von Eichhörnchen Nusper”.

Comment: Your Wikipedia idea was good, but it took slightly more effort: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatrix_Potter

Comment: @CarstenS Alright, thank you so much! You can add a short answer so I select it ;)

Comment: Who told you to translate the title, if you don't know German? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CarstenS wrote in the comments there is a German version of the book called

> Die Geschichte von Eichhörnchen Nusper

But ... you were told to translate it, not to look it up. So, who told you to translate it? A friend? Go forward and use the "official" German title. A teacher? In this case let's take a deeper look for some "own work".

As you said the book is called

> The Tale of Squirrel Nutkin

"The Tale of" can be translated as

> Die Geschichte von/vom
>
> Das Märchen von/vom
>
> Die Sage von/vom

So ... is the story a "Geschichte", "Märchen" or "Sage". In this case the most fitting one is "Geschichte". As "The Tale of Squirrel Nutkin" is neither a fairy tale (Märchen) nor a fable/legend (Sage).

What about Squirrel Nutkin? Is Squirrel his forename and Nutkin his lastname? Remember, the same author wrote "The Tale of Peter Rabbit" and it's main character  is called "Peter Rabbit" or "Peter Hase" in German. Let's take a [quick look into the book](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Squirrel_Nutkin). No, his name is Nutkin and he's a squirrel. That's it.

Let's say we'll call him Nutkin for a moment as well, then by now there a two options

> Die Geschichte von/vom Eichhörnchen Nutkin
>
> Die Geschichte von Nutkin dem Eichhörnchen

Now Nutkin ... let's say you want to "Germanize" it (you don't have to as it's a name, but now that we have gone so far and it's common in a lot of books).

Nutkin can be seperated into Nut and kin. Nut is easy: Nuss. kin is a harder nut to crack. [These](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-kin) [sites](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-kin) say it can be a diminutive suffix. In German diminutive suffixes usually are -lein or -chen. So we could call him

> Nusslein / Nüsslein
>
> Nusschen / Nüsschen

with me prefering the ü-versions, as they are more natural. (Most likely there are other possible combinations/variants as Nüsslein/Nüsschen sound a little bit silly, but this is my answer and I don't want to dig any further ;) )

Finally, let us put the pieces together:

To be honest, I'm not sure wether to use "von" or "vom" as von (as in the official German book) would refer to a forename/surname combination. As in "Die Geschichte von Beatrix Potter" in contrast to "Die Geschichte vom Hasen Peter".

So I would suggest

> Die Geschichte vom Eichhörnchen Nüsschen
>
> Die Geschichte von Nüsslein dem Eichhörchen

Comment: Clearly, the last one is most natural.